# How to pick a subset of the rows of a matrix data sample so that the resulting correlation matrix of the curated data approaches the identity matrix?

Tags: correlation-matrix

If I have a data sample in the form of a matrix $X$ of dimensions $n \times m$, is there a standard procedure to optimally pick $n'$ rows ($n'$ fixed) of the matrix $X$ so that $C_{X'}$, the correlation matrix of the resulting matrix $X'$ of dimensions $n' \times m$, is the closest to the identity matrix?

I am relatively open-minded as to what "closest" is supposed to mean here, but we could interpret it for example as $\min_{X' \in A}||C_{X'} - I_m||_F$ with $A$ being the set of matrices that can be obtained by picking $n'$ rows of $X$.

Comment: Is $n^\prime$ specified as part of the problem or is it to be determined as part of the solution?  How should we measure how good any solution might be--that is, how do you define "optimal"?

Comment: I modified my initial post so that it would be more precise. $n'$ is fixed and "optimal" means that $X'$ minimizes $||C_{X'} - I_m ||_F$ with $C_{X'}$ correlation matrix of $X'$.